# WPF: erratic memory consumption patterns

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to decide wether to write my new application in WPF or WinForms and I can't figure out WPF's erratic memory consumption patterns.

Just as an example, I created a basic WPF application in Visual Studio 2013, with a StackPanel and a TextBox. Just like this:

```
<Window x:Class="SingleTextBoxWpfTestApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel Margin="20">
    <TextBox></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

There's no code behind, no ViewModel - just this.

I start the program and it is already at 6.5 MB. Then the following oddity occurs: I left-click the text box once to place the cursor in there, sit back with popcorn and watch the task manager go crazy. For the duration of about a minute, the process's memory just keeps going up and up and up, until it stops at almost 11 MB. Just because the textbox received focus.

If I move the focus to another process (even if the WPF process is still visible), the joyride stops.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how it can be stopped?

Comment: Which framework version are you using?

Comment: . Net framework 4.5. Does that actually matter?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue: in my case (VS 2013 e Win10) after I start my application, it uses 12 MB. If I focus the `TextBox` used memory grows up to 13.4 MB - not so terrible as in your case. What if you put another kind of focusable control (for example a `Button`) in your window instead of the `TextBox`?